# Loop through HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap, kotlin

I'm trying to loop through a HashMap with a String as key and an Object of my Class as value. I want rek1 to have key "A" and rek2 key "B".

Here's my code:

```
private Map<String, List<X2Y2>> areaMap = new HashMap<String, List<X2Y2>>();
ArrayList<X2Y2> arrList = new ArrayList<X2Y2>();
X2Y2 rek1 = new X2Y2(1.0,1.0, 2.0, 2.0);
X2Y2 rek2 = new X2Y2(3.0,3.0, 4.0, 4.0);
arrList.add(rek1);
arrList.add(rek2);
areaMap.put("A", arrList);

for (Object key : areaMap.keySet()) {
   String lKey = (String) key;
   List<X2Y2> list = areaMap.get(key);
   Log.i("Worku?", list.toString());
}
```

`class X2Y2(var x1: Double, var y1: Double, var x2: Double, var y2: Double) {}`

The thing is that I can only get the key value, not the list with my X2Y2. Anyone got any tip that can help me get my X2Y2 values ?

Comment: i would use a Map.Entry<String, List<X2Y2>> to iterate over it

Comment: you could not let rek1 to have key "A" and rek2 key "B", because they are the element of the list that is the value of the HashMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `areaMap.get(key);` to `areaMap.get(lKey);`

I do think you should iterate using a entry set so that you could get the value easier though

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<X2Y2>> kv : areaMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(kv.getValue());
}
```

Comment: System.out: [io.agilevision.proximity.indoor.X2Y2@802c399, io.agilevision.proximity.indoor.X2Y2@21c165e] is the output i get.. Do i just need to loop through the list after that or what?

Comment: yeah, you could do a `kv.getValue().forEach(System.out::println);`
if you want to print out the values or do whatever with them